# Why does my breakline not work it seems right

Tags: java, string, for-loop, jlabel

I use simple way of writting it in a temp string and later on put it in a JLabel because it wont make breakline. and i got problem showing the button it doenst show anyhing.

```
public String printBestillingsordre(){
        JButton button = new JButton("Varemodtaget");

        for(HentbestillingsordreRegistrer hentboregistrer: hbor){
        if(status == "Leveret"){    

        temp += "Ordre Status: " + hentboregistrer.BestillingsStatus+" \n " +
        "LeverandoerID: "+ hentboregistrer.LeverandoerID+" \n ";


        }else{
            temp += hentboregistrer.BestillingsStatus+ button + "\n" + 
                    "LeverandoerID: "+ hentboregistrer.LeverandoerID+"\n";
        }
        System.out.println(temp);

    }
        return temp;
}
```

where i call it, it looks like this

```
hboh.Hentbestillingsordre();
        hboh.printBestillingsordre();
        tilbagetilhovedmenu = new JButton("HovedMenu");
        add(tilbagetilhovedmenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel test = hboh.HentOrdreGUI();
        add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        tilbagetilhovedmenu.addActionListener(handler);
```

Comment: don't forget to vote and chose question as good if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i don't see where you declare your temp String, then

There are two thing I would change in your code :

1)Use a string builder 
2)Use equalsIgnoreCase
3)Check what are you doing with that `button` inside your string concatenation
as it doesn't make much sense

```
    public String printBestillingsordre(){

        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        JButton button = new JButton("Varemodtaget");

        for(HentbestillingsordreRegistrer hentboregistrer: hbor){
        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Leveret"){    
            temp.append("<html>");
            temp.append("Ordre Status: ");
            temp.append(hentboregistrer.BestillingsStatus);
            temp.append("<br>");
            temp.append("LeverandoerID: ");
            temp.append(hentboregistrer.LeverandoerID);
            temp.append("<br>");
            temp.append("</html>");

        }else{
            temp.append("<html>");
            temp.append(hentboregistrer.BestillingsStatus);
            temp.append(button);     // whatever you're trying to append from button
            temp.append("<br>");
            temp.append("LeverandoerID: ");
            temp.append(hentboregistrer.LeverandoerID);
            temp.append("<br>");
            temp.append("</html>");
        }
        System.out.println(temp.toSTring());

    }
        return temp.toSTring();
}
```

EDIT:

Workaround 1(used in my example): You could consider adding `<html></html>` tags (add to beginning and end) and everytime you need a newline use a `<br>` tag

Workaround 2:Use a `SwingX Label` :

```
XLabel label = new JXLabel();
label.setLineWrap(true);
```

Keep in mind that if you're developing a multithreaded app then consider using a StringBuffer as that is syncronized with the treads.For more info check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786023/multithreading-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder) question

Comment: though its a really good suggestion to use stringbuilder instead of string.i don't really see why OP's original code wouldn't work ?? all i can see is the use of `==` operator instead of equals.

Comment: But i though it in a JLabel, and JLabel doenst recognize "\n"

Comment: It's about using a good practice, if you want to write code at least write it good, beside that there's that button inside the append that intrigues me, waiting for OP still.

Comment: Actually JLabel is not intended for new line text check my edit for the some workarounds

Comment: forget the button. i'll remove the button. the breakline doenst work.

Comment: @LucianEnache yepp, it'd be good if you mentioned the consequences of using a string builder in an multithreaded app. and an alternative for it (StringBuffer) in your answer :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR In that case I'll add that too :) thx for pointing it out

Comment: It work, but my idea with button was to every row i want a button that i can press. but i have no idea how to implement this

Comment: Well that's a different question then.

Comment: Shall i make a new "ask question to that"?

Comment: I definitely suggest you to.