# StringBuffer and Multithreading

Tags: java, thread-safety, stringbuffer

`StringBuffer` can handle multiple threads through `synchronization` If your text can changes, and will be accessed from multiple threads, use a StringBuffer because `StringBuffer` is synchronous.

Can anyone explain me when does the Multithreading happen? Do we create threads in our program implementing `runnable interface or extending Thread class` or is it `OS` based?.

Comment: Ohoh... seems you have to read up on threading in Java first. Yes, you can start threads by implementing the Runnable interface and then starting a new thread. For example in Swing applications you usually have more than one thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multithreading - StringBuffer and StringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786023/multithreading-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)

Comment: Sane uses of StringBuffer across multiple threads are very rare. note: each append can occur in any order, so each thread must only call append once for something which must be continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The threading can happen any number of ways. If you are creating threads (e.g. `extends Thread`) or if you are creating objects that get passed off to a threading model of some kind (e.g. `implements Runnable`) or even if you just have code somewhere that handles something like events (e.g. a callback function). How the threads are created isn't important. In any case, when you have something like this:

```
public String someMethod()
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append("Some Method");
    return(b.toString());
}
```

You know that is thread safe. Any access to the `StringBuilder`'s `append()` method doesn't need to by synchronized. However, if you have something like this (just an example):

```
public class Test
{
    StringBuffer b;

    public Test()
    {
        b = new StringBuffer();
    }

    public String someMethod()
    {
        b.append("Some Method");
        return(b.toString());
    }
}
```

Here, you can see that more than one "thread" of execution could call `someMethod()`, and since they would all be access the `StringBuffer`, it needs to be synchronized. It could be the case that only one thread ever calls the method at any one given time, but the way this is written doesn't prohibit 2 threads calling it at the same time. If a `StringBuilder` is used (not thread safe) you're likely to run into problems.

Comment: How come in the first case multiple threads cannot be accessed and in the second case it happens.

Comment: @Kevin multiple threads can access the first method, sure. But as you can see, each time the method is called, it has it's own `StringBuilder` within its scope. So every thread that calls that method has its own `StringBuilder`, whereas in the second case, all the threads *share* a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @Kevin In the `StringBuffer`'s case, more or less. You should still take a look at the Java Concurrency docs anyways, especially the section on Synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

It is either `'implementing runnable'` and `'extending Thread'`

If the resource (here `StringBuffer` ) is shared among the multiple thread (java processes) / Assume that `StringBuffer` is defined in non monitored scope (i.e outside `synchronize{}` block )

In that case multiple threads will not wait in que to access the `StringBuffer` instance as there is no monitor/ or lock needs to be obtained to modify the instance.

More info on [java concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your program is not capable of doing two different actions/events at the same time. Then you need to think about `Threads`. From a logical point of view, `multithreading` means multiple lines of a single program. In this case, the operating system is treating the programs as two separate and distinct processes

Java's creators have graciously designed two ways of creating threads: `implementing an interface and extending a class`. A simple case cane be when you are having a Log file and multiple threads are logging errors or warnings `and` writing to that log file.

A dog's sense of smell is `polymorphic`. If the dog smells a cat, it will bark and run after it. If the dog smells it food, it will salivate and run to its bowl. The sense of smell is at work in both situations. The difference is what is being smelled, that is , the type of data operated upon by the dog's nose!

Let's dive with an example:

**// Here is our main class.**

```
class ThreadTest2 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyClass("thread1: "));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyClass("thread2: "));

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        boolean thread1IsAlive = true;
        boolean thread2IsAlive = true;

        do {
            if (thread1IsAlive && !thread1.isAlive()) {
                thread1IsAlive = false;
                System.out.println("Thread 1 is dead.");
            }

            if (thread2IsAlive && !thread2.isAlive()) {
                thread2IsAlive = false;
                System.out.println("Thread 2 is dead.");
            }
        } while (thread1IsAlive || thread2IsAlive);

    }

}
```

**// Here is our class which implements runnable interface.**

```
class MyClass implements Runnable {
    static String message[] = { "Java", "is", "hot,", "aromatic"};
    String name;

    public MyClass(String id){
        name = id;
    }

    public void run(){

        for(int i=0;i<message.length;++i) {
            randomWait();
            System.out.println(name+message[i]);
        }
    }

    void randomWait(){
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(3000*Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
        }
    }
}
```

This program creates two threads of execution, `thread1 and thread2`, from the MyThread class. It then starts both threads and executes a do statement that waits for the threads to die. The threads display the Java is hot, aromatic. message word by word, while waiting a short, random amount of time between each word. `Because both threads share the console window`, the program's output identifies which threads were able to write to the console at various times during the program's execution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly create extra `Thread`s via, for example, the `Runnable` interface or the `Thread` class for multithreading to be a concern. This also holds true for certain `Java EE` situations, where the JVM creates extra threads.

If the `OS` uses extra threads in the background, it, and not you, is responsible for thread safety, so this is nothing you need to worry about.

You can read more in the [Concurrency section of the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).